# How does fs.readFile(<Buffer> | <integer) work?

Tags: node.js, fs

We can give a string arg to fs.readFile to represent a file path

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

But I notice the [offical documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) said:

`fs.readFile(path[, options], callback)`

`path` can be a Buffer or an integer. Then I try

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile(1, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Then it throw an error.

I am really confused, how this arg can be a integer?
Can anybody gives a example?

Answer (score 3):

The integer argument that you can pass should represent a valid file descriptor. For example, `stdin` typically has file descriptor 0, so to read a "file" from `stdin` you can use this:

```
fs.readFile(0, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

Instead of 0, you can also use `process.stdin.fd`.

Another way to get a file descriptor is to use [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation: `path` is either `string` or `Buffer` or `URL` or `integer`, and the description of the parameter is: "filename or file descriptor".

- `string` | `Buffer` | `URL` - `path` is  treated as a filename (something like `"/path/to/your/file"`)
- `integer` - `path` is treated as a [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

So if you pass an `integer`, NodeJS accesses the file by the file descriptor.

Read more about [how NodeJS handles file descriptors](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_descriptors_1).

Comment: It seems `Buffer` is rather a representation of the filename string, as in [`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt Whoops, you're right, I stand corrected. I edited my answer accordingly.